# The @login_required decoration is not working in Django (user not authenticated?)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to set up a login page and I am trying to use the `@login_required` decoration. However, whenever I try and log in with valid credentials I am re-directed to the 'login' page (set to re-direct unauthenticated users). I am not sure if the problem is in the @login_required decoration or perhaps the login() function is not authenticating the user.

Here is my code for the register form:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password']
```

code for login function in views.py:

```
def login_user(request):
if request.method =="GET":
    return render(request, "main/login.html", {})
else:
    username = escape(request.POST['userfield'])
    password = escape(request.POST['passfield'])
    
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        user = None
    
    if user is None:

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
        except:
            user = None

            if user is None:
                messages.info(request, "*Sorry, that username or email does not exist")
                return redirect('login')
    
    pword = user.password

    if check_password(password, pword):
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('homepage')
        
    else:
        messages.info(request, '*Sorry, that was an incorrect password')
        return redirect('login')
```

my model for User in models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and my function to reach the 'homepage' after login:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='login')
def homepage(request):
   return render(request, "main/homepage.html", {})
```

Comment: If is this your custom user model, so you should use `AbstractUser` and `AbstractBaseUser`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had considered this as well, but I think I am going to just create my own sessions using the request.session option provided by Django in order to create user session use boolean in the datbase to authenticate users :)

Comment: @CameronGrant django provides a lot of out of the box support so you don't have to do what you're describing. Managing users, session and auth is the reason to use django in the first place. My advice is- use what's there. Manufacturing and managing you're entire session middleware, authentication system, users, etc is going to cause more headaches down the road than you can possibly imagine with little-to-no benefit whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly authenticate the user before logging in.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
```

More information in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked at this, but unfortunately the authenticate function does not seem to work for me. I think this is because I am using my own forms for registration and login rather than Djangos ones, hence why I have written my own code for authentication

Answer (score 0):

When you make custom user model, so you should always use [`AbstractBaseUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser).

> `Note:` It's also not a good practice to name same your models, django already has `User` model in the `django.contrib.auth`, so change its name.

So, you haven't specified the custom user model, so you should not able to authenticate, as by default authentication model is `User` which is at `django.contrib.auth`. So, with the current code when you make superuser through `python manage.py createsuperuser` and then you authenticate, so it will work.

You should use `@login_required(login_url='login')` instead of <s>`@login_required(redirect_field_name='login')`</s>.